# PrimeNG - How to change the style of pTemplate="caption" in p-table for a single component

Tags: angular, sass, primeng, ng-template, p-table

I'd like to change the background color of the caption cell of my `p-table` in only one component, how can I do?

I tried `<ng-template pTemplate="caption" class="myStyle">`

and     `.myStyle{ background: rgb(9,169,121) !important; }`
in my.component.scss

but it doesn't work.

Help me! Thanks!

---

Edit: Finally it works! I see the answer of @Antikhippe, but I had to add

> :host ::ng-deep {
> #myTable {
> .p-datatable-thead{
> background: red;
> }
> **.p-datatable .p-datatable-thead > tr > th {
> background: inherit;
> }**
> } }

Comment: The result is very bad, because the background of the whole "caption" cell is not colored, but only of a central row. Thanks anyway for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pTemplate="caption"` will only fit part of your table header, you have to work on `p-datatable-header` class:

Try this:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  #myTable {
    .p-datatable-header {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

I surrounded `p-datatable-header` class with `#myTable` to apply this CSS only for a table with `myTable` id:

```
<p-table id="myTable" [value]="products">
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesections-demo-g9hcay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Comment: You can see it works in my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesections-demo-g9hcay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss), have you added the `id` property to your table?

Comment: I see that in your StackBlitz it works, but in my case it was not working. To what you told me I had to add .p-datatable .p-datatable-thead > tr > th {
  background: inherit;
 }