# PrimeNg expand table overlap root table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I have a problem with primeNg table.
I use child table printed with rowexpansion.
It works well but when scrolling is enabled child table overlap header of parent
How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting z-index to 0 for thead element in child table.
This topic helped me:
[PrimeNG - How to change the style of pTemplate="caption" in p-table for a single component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64720375/primeng-how-to-change-the-style-of-ptemplate-caption-in-p-table-for-a-single)

Solution:

1. Add id to child table

   `<p-table id="childTable"`
2. Add below code to corresponding scss

   `:host ::ng-deep {
          #childTable {
             .p-datatable-thead {
                  z-index: 0;
             }
          }
       }`